# java multi-thread sychronized code block when lock released but not acquired immediately by other thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to multi-thread and I find the result of the code below is interesting.

```java
public class SellTicket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T2 runnableObj = new T2();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnableObj);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnableObj);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(runnableObj);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();

    }
}


class T2 implements Runnable {

    private int ticketNum = 10;

    public void sell() {

        System.out.println("" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " enter sell method");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " enter sync code block！");
            if (ticketNum <= 0) {
                System.out.println("sold out" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);

                ticketNum -= 1;

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " sell one ticket, rest " + ticketNum + "\n");


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (ticketNum != 0) {
            sell();
        }

    }

}
```

I'm learning to use the sychronize code block, and the output is

```
Thread-0 enter sell method
Thread-2 enter sell method
Thread-1 enter sell method
Thread-2 enter sync code block！
Thread-2 sell one ticket, rest 9

Thread-2 enter sell method
Thread-1 enter sync code block！
Thread-1 sell one ticket, rest 8

Thread-1 enter sell method
Thread-0 enter sync code block！
Thread-0 sell one ticket, rest 7

Thread-0 enter sell method
//...
```

I'm confused that when `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " sell one ticket, rest " + ticketNum + "\n");` ends, the lock is freed, right? why the next output is **Thread-x enter sell method** but not **Thread-x enter sync code block**? it seems that when the lock is freed, the other thread does not accquired the lock immediately(I think they should invoke the sychronized code block right away)

I've tried many times, so is there some mechanism or the output is just a coincidence ?

Comment: You will probably start seeing the behaviour you expect if you add another `sleep` after leaving the `synchronized` block (or move the first print statement to after the first sleep).

Comment: I m thinking that it takes some time for the thread to "wake up" or even to decide which thread gets the lock. It probably is faster for the currently running thread (thread 2) to immediately complete the sell() method, then goes to the next iteration of the while loop and print "enter sell method".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

experiment unit 1998X said,

> I m thinking that it takes some time for the thread to "wake up" or even to decide which thread gets the lock. It probably is faster for the currently running thread (thread 2) to immediately complete the sell() method, then goes to the next iteration of the while loop and print "enter sell method".

To put it another way: It's not the job of the OS scheduler to act as a referee who ensures that different threads in the same program each get a fair share of CPU time. Threads in the same program are supposed to *cooperate* with each other, not compete with each other.

The goal of the scheduler in a typical workstation/server/mobile-device operating system is to make efficient use of the CPUs. If two threads want to access the same mutex at the same time, then it's more efficient to award the mutex to the thread that's already *on* some CPU than it is to waste CPU cycles by swapping that one out, and swap in some other thread that was "asleep" waiting for it.

Some programming environments have a thing with a name like "*fair* mutex," which behaves more like how you were expecting `synchronized(this)` to behave. You can have one in Java if you construct a [`new ReentrantLock(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#%3Cinit%3E(boolean)). But, if using a fair mutex solves a problem for you, then that's a sign that your design is weak—not getting the full benefit of using threads.

Answer (score 0):

When thread-x was running,there was no need for JVM thread scheduler to pre-empt thread-x and thus allow thread-x to run.It allows thread-x to run to completion but was encountered with sleep which no longer requires CPU,thus thread-y gets the chance,fetches the lock and prints "enter .. thread-y".

Also there is no variable or construct which ensures "happen-before relationship" after or before synchronized block.